# Using :joins in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

Greetings 
I have 3 db tables:

**Types**
  id
  name

**Sources**
  id
  name
  type_id

**Operations**
  id
  source_id
  comment
  ...

and models for each:

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sources, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
  has_many :operations, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Operation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :source
  default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'
end
```

In Operation#index controller i have code for getting data (generated by scaffolding)

```
@operations = Operation.all
```

And piece of view *operations/index.html.erb* also generated by scaffolding

```
<% @operations.each do |operation| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= operation.source_id %></td>
    <td><%= operation.comment %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to use *source.name* instead of *operation.source_id*

I tried to do:

-replace operation.source_id to operation.sources.name # doesn't work

-tried to using :joins, and can't get Sources table fields

```
irb(main):057:0> Operation.first( :joins => :source )
=> #<Operation id: 2088, source_id: 1, summ: 10.0, comment: "", created_at: "2011-01-01 07:39:45", updated_at: nil>
```

or

```
irb(main):063:0> Operation.first( :joins => 'INNER JOIN sources ON operations.source_id = sources.id' )
=> #<Operation id: 2088, source_id: 1, summ: 10.0, comment: "", created_at: "2011-01-01 07:39:45", updated_at: nil>
```

How I must properly use *:joins* for get additional field? 
Or there is another approach to get combined tables data.

And why in the *operations/show.html.erb* i can use *<%= @operation.source.name %>* and successfully get *source.name*, but in the *operations/index.html.er*b can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @operations.each do |operation| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= operation.source.name %></td>
    <td><%= operation.comment %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I'd also recommend changing your `#index` method to use an `includes` statement to avoid an N+1 situation (i.e. running a separate database query for each individual operation's source).

```
@operations = Operation.includes(:source).all
```

Comment: It's not working.
Console:
irb(main):011:0* Operation.includes(:source).first
=> #<Operation id: 2088, source_id: 1, summ: 10.0, comment: "", created_at: "2011-01-01 07:39:45", updated_at: nil>

browser:
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: What does doing the following in the console give you: `Operation.includes(:source).first.source.name`? Since you're getting the undefined method on nil, this could be an indicator that you have some `Operation` objects which are not linked to any source. If this is the case, and it was intentional, you may want to use something like `<%= operation.source ? operation.source.name : "No Source" %>`.

Comment: Operation.includes(:source).first.source.name gets me Source.name. How i can get source.name in my view? Here is solution in my answer. But I would like to know how to get source.name using your approach

Comment: damn. I've created new rails app, generate 2 same models and added some records to DB and it's work even with `@operations = Operation.all`. Thanks for helping me

Comment: The problem was with some records, where absent some sources. This approach `<%= operation.source ? operation.source.name : "No Source" %>` solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

opearions#index

```
@operations = Operation.all :joins => :source, :select => '*'
```

operations/index.html.erb

```
<% @operations.each do |operation| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= operation.name %></td>
...
```

Comment: It may work, but it's not really the "Rails way" to do it. I would recommend to do it like dmarkow described. That really should work.